# Does tikz have meaningful whitespace?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This latex compiles for me perfectly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,text width=1cm, level distance = 1.2cm}] 
\node[text width=2.5cm]  {A} 
      child{ node  {A} 
      child{ node  {A} }
  }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

However this latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,text width=1cm, level distance = 1.2cm}] 
\node[text width=2.5cm]  {A} 
      child{ node  {A} 
      child{ node  {A} 

}
  }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives me:

```
Runaway argument?
{ node {A} child{ node {A} 
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@collect@child@code was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10 
     
?
```

What's going on? Does tikx have meaningful whitespace (the only thing that has changed is the addition of new carriage returns before one of the } characters)? My googling is just giving me ways of putting whitespace in the pdf...

Comment: In general no, but in your particular case (in tree structure) has.

Comment: BTW, the \par is how TeX interprets blank lines.  This is before any extraneous text is dumped into a bit box.

Comment: Spaces are mostly ignored in Ti*k*Z, with due exception for textual parts. However it doesn't allow blank lines in certain arguments; technically because the macros are not declared `\long`. At the outer level a blank line is not a problem, because `\par` tokens are ignored in what is eventually an `\hbox`; there may be good reasons not to allow blank lines in that situation (or it is just that the developers didn't think to users putting blank lines in that position).

Comment: @egreg thank you! :)

Comment: @egreg - popping back here to say that if you would like to make that an official answer I'd accept it :)

Comment: @Joe You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are usually ignored when parsing Ti*k*Z instructions except, of course, when text to be typeset is absorbed.

Blank lines between Ti*k*Z statements (that is after a semicolon) are always allowed, as far as I know, because at the outer level TeX is building an `\hbox`.

However, blank lines are not allowed everywhere, as you found out.

Technically, the macro that's being executed when a `child` note is being processed is `\tikz@collect@child@code` that's not defined as `\long`, so you get the error message about a “Runaway argument”.

Why this is not the case, when other internal macros are `\long`, should be asked to the developers; possibly a precise choice, due to the particular situation, or just they didn't think to add `\long` in front of `\def`.

A quick look at the code reveals that a list is being constructed and it's quite likely that blank lines in it might disrupt the later job of displaying the nodes. Actually just a few macros are declared `\long` in `tikz.code.tex`, precisely nine of them, mostly related to “pin”.

So avoid blank lines, except between statements.

Comment: To support blank lines, except for the `\long` prefix, the tikz tree parser has to handle `\par` as well. There's a similar problem in tikz graph parser, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1001.

Answer (score 1):

the error is caused due to the extra blank line after the second child node in your code --remove it and things will be normal

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,text width=1cm, level distance = 1.2cm}] 
\node[text width=2.5cm]  {A} 
child{ node  {A} 
    child{ node  {A} 
                }%<---------------------------removed blank line
}
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```